# Oracle Error, moving data between databases

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am moving some data between two databases and have had much success, but then I encountered a problem doing the same kind of query that I've been doing.

The query:

```
INSERT INTO INTERNET.WEBSECURITY@crmtest SELECT * FROM INTERNET.WEBSECURITY;
```

The Error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Any ideas on what this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a plsql variable which is not big enough or it has greater size than the column data type.

Comment: So it could be that one has id's 1-10 and the next one starts on id's 40-80 which would ruin the sequence?
Is there any ways to get around this?

Comment: It can be. To able to get a specific answer you should give more details about your case. If id numbers are not matching try to convert the data, if it's doesn't matter to convert of course. But my advice is, giving more detail makes easier to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Got it solved, disabled a trigger preventing what I was trying to do, updated the sequence to start on the next number, and re-enabled the trigger. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition: Assign/insert a non-numeric value to a numeric variable/column.
Probably your table columns are a bit different in datatypes and sizes. I do not see any variables in your example.